# Using the iTunes app, from another app

Tags: ios, swift3, itunes-app

Inside an `iOS` app of mine I want to set a button which is going to allow me to  view a movie in the iTunes app.

Is that possible?
If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3, iOS 10 and above.**

```
if let url = URL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between https://www.apple.com/itunes/ and itms://itunes.apple.com/ ? Is the last one some kind if deep link?